# Switch between timer2 and manually setting output of pin 3

Tags: pwm

I have a 62.5 kHz square wave created by timer2 on the pin 3. I would like to be able to use digitalWrite(3, HIGH) to force pin 3 high for several clock cycles, but then I would like it to return the 62.5 kHz square wave. Is there a way to reset a single output without resetting the entire program?

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(3, OUTPUT); //Output for OCR2B (Timer 2)
  //The following block allows sets the Timer2 properties for PWM
  TCCR2A = _BV(COM2A1) | _BV(COM2B1) | _BV(WGM21) | _BV(WGM20);
  TCCR2B = _BV(WGM22) | _BV(CS20);
  OCR2A = 255; //Sets the period to 16us (62.5kHz)
  OCR2B = 0; //Sets the duty cycle of the signal (8-bit(255) resolution)
}

void loop() {
  int pot = analogRead(A0);
  int duty = map(pot, 0, 1023, 0, 255); //scale to duty cycle resolution
  OCR2B = duty; //set duty cycle
  delay(10000); //arbitrary wait time
  digitalWrite(3, HIGH);
  delay(10000); //arbitrary wait time
  //undo the digitalWrite to continue the pulse train here
}
```

Comment: Can you show how you are currently setting up the square wave? That is, are you using a library in Arduino, or are you using the timer/counter registers directly to produce the waveform? Are the "several clock cycles" actual MCU clock cycles, or cycles of the 62.5 kHz waveform?

Comment: "several clock cycles" is just an arbitrary time where the output is force either high or low.

Comment: please do not put code in comments .... somebody moved the code to your question, where it is supposed to be .... please delete the two comments

Answer (score 1):

If you clear the clock select bits in `TCCR2B`, then the PWM stops and you can control the port normally. To re-start the PWM, set the `CS20` bit just as you did in `setup()`.

Comment: to clear the bits would i set tccr2b = 0; or just the _bv(0) part?

Comment: `TCCR2B &= ~(_BV(CS20));` will clear just CS20 bit and leave all else the same.